# error: failed parsing overlays when build AOSP source

Tags: android, android-source, aapt2

Today I has downloaded AOSP and I am trying build newest android version with lunch option is aosp_car_x86-userdebug
But after about 50 minutes, I got the message log as below...

> warn: removing resource com.android.bluetooth:string/map_acceptance_timeout_message without required default value.
>   warn: removing resource com.android.bluetooth:string/map_auth_notif_message without required default value.
>   warn: removing resource com.android.bluetooth:string/map_auth_notif_ticker without required default value.
>   warn: removing resource com.android.bluetooth:string/map_auth_notif_title without required default value.
>   warn: removing resource com.android.bluetooth:string/map_authentication_timeout_message without required default value.
>   warn: removing resource com.android.bluetooth:string/map_defaultname without required default value.
>   warn: removing resource com.android.bluetooth:string/map_defaultnumber without required default value.
>   warn: removing resource com.android.bluetooth:string/map_localPhoneName without required default value.
>   warn: removing resource com.android.bluetooth:string/map_session_key_dialog_header without required default value.
>   warn: removing resource com.android.bluetooth:string/map_session_key_dialog_title without required default value.
>   warn: removing resource com.android.bluetooth:string/map_unknownName without required default value.
>   [ 70% 51582/73245] AAPT2 link out/target/product/generic_x86/obj/APPS/Contacts_intermediates/package-res.apk
>   warn: removing resource com.android.contacts:bool/config_editor_include_phonetic_name without required default value.
>   [ 70% 51584/73245] //frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib:SettingsLib aapt2 link
>   FAILED: out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/package-res.apk out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/gen/proguard.options out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/gen/R.jar out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/R.txt out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/extra_packages
>   out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/aapt2 link -o out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/package-res.apk --no-static-lib-packages --manifest out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/manifest_fixer/AndroidManifest.xml  --min-sdk-version 21 --target-sdk-version 21 --version-code 28 --version-name  Q -I out/soong/.intermediates/prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-v4/android_common/package-res.apk -I out/soong/.intermediates/prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview/android_common/package-res.apk -I out/soong/.intermediates/prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/androidx.preference_preference/android_common/package-res.apk -I out/soong/.intermediates/prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/androidx.appcompat_appcompat/android_common/package-res.apk -I out/soong/.intermediates/prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime/android_common/package-res.apk -I out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/core/res/framework-res/android_common/package-res.apk --static-lib --java out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/gen/aapt2/R --proguard out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/gen/proguard.options --output-text-symbols out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/R.txt @out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/res.list -R @out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/overlay.list && out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_zip -write_if_changed -jar -o out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/gen/R.jar -C out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/gen/aapt2/R -D out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/gen/aapt2/R &&out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/extract_jar_packages -i out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/gen/R.jar -o out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/extra_packages --prefix '--extra-packages '
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: error: resource dimen/drawer_icon_margin does not override an existing resource.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: note: define an  tag or use --auto-add-overlay.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: error: resource dimen/drawer_icon_size does not override an existing resource.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: note: define an  tag or use --auto-add-overlay.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: error: resource dimen/drawer_item_top_bottom_margin does not override an existing resource.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: note: define an  tag or use --auto-add-overlay.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: error: resource dimen/drawer_spacer_height does not override an existing resource.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: note: define an  tag or use --auto-add-overlay.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: error: resource dimen/drawer_width does not override an existing resource.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: note: define an  tag or use --auto-add-overlay.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: error: resource dimen/medium_text_size does not override an existing resource.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: note: define an  tag or use --auto-add-overlay.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: error: resource dimen/normal_icon_size does not override an existing resource.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: note: define an  tag or use --auto-add-overlay.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: error: resource dimen/small_text_size does not override an existing resource.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: note: define an  tag or use --auto-add-overlay.
>   out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/SettingsLib/android_common/aapt2/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values_dimens.arsc.flat: error: failed to merge resource table.
>   error: failed parsing overlays.
>   15:45:18 ninja failed with: exit status 1
>
> failed to build some targets (46:10 (mm:ss))

Could you please take a look and tell me what are problem with my issue.

Comment: By add resource 
    <add-resource type="dimen" name="value_show_in_log_file"></add-resource>
I can build the source code successfully

Answer (score 2):

I had run into similar issue.
Just add below code for each problematic resource in file :

> packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values/dimens.xml

```
<add-resource type="dimen" name="small_text_size"></add-resource>
```

It would work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that there is missing some resource.
Please copy the missing resource to `SettingsLib/SettingsLib/res/dimens.xml.`
the missing resource is in [here](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/res/values/dimens.xml#21)

Please remember to remove the "`normal_icon_size`" item.
because it has been added to the `dimens.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common issues when upgrading to new AOSP codebase on your existing AOSP changes. To support target specific resource changes, AOSP provides overlay where we can change the resources values as per the target need.

**Problem:**

Let's understand when this error will come.

For example if there is some AOSP package named "SettingsProvider" which has a string resource named as "should_provide_gps" and is not present anymore in new AOSP codebase But your target overlay has that variable.

**Solution:**

Remove that variable from overlay because overlay is meant
    to be overriden existing resources. If no such resource is present
    in the given path, then having same resource in overlay does not
    make any sense.